# How SOAP web services are communicate through Eureka only? not direct to each other

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, microservices, netflix-eureka

I am working on a POC to show my manager.I have created 4 microservice using springboot (1 is MVC + 2 SOAP + 1 simple spring boot for Eureka) .First I went to a tutorial, [This](http://www.springboottutorial.com/creating-microservices-with-spring-boot-part-1-getting-started) tutorial developed these services completely designed on REST architecture. I read all articles in the tutorial that helps me a lot to understand.

But my requirement is to create same type of application but using SOAP web services. Anyhow with the help of [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/jax-ws) ,i have created: 2 SOAP  web service + 1 MVC + 1 simple spring boot application(Eureka). All 3 services are registered in Eureka service, i can see in Eureka Console also:

[image: PFA]

all are up and running. They are communicating with soap client perfectly. I ran the application, It's working perfectly.

But when i give demo to manager he was not completely satisfied. He told me that

> business logic wise its fine but your services are communicating directly each other, there is no role of Eureka in your application. In your application Eureka is showing which service is up and running, nothing else. This is not complete microservice pattern which you shown to me.

Then i google about it and explore the microservice architecture. I understood it.
But my problem is my services are design with SOAP and i did not find any relevant article or any tutorial which could help me on this. All articles are for REST design.

I even explored [this article[7](https://spring.io/blog/2015/07/14/microservices-with-spring) but it did not help me a lot.

So can some please provide any help/link/code which can help me as per my requirement. I need a application in which SOAP services are communicating through Eureka only.

Answer (score 0):

Eureka is the registry of you services. They don't communicate through it.
What you can do is to get registered hosts from Eureka-service-resgistry.
You can do it by using [ribbon client](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-ribbon.html#_using_the_ribbon_api_directly). You get host and port and can use that in you SOAP URL. If there are multiple instances of the same service you will also get load-balancing on the client side.

```
public class MyClass {
    @Autowired
    private LoadBalancerClient loadBalancer;

    public void doStuff() {
        ServiceInstance instance = loadBalancer.choose("stores");
        URI storesUri = URI.create(String.format("http://%s:%s", instance.getHost(), instance.getPort()));
        // ... do something with the URI
    }
}
```